# How to insert objects into an NSMutableArray based on cells selected in UITableView in iOS?

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I have a `UITableViewController` that has a `UITableView` whose cells have a button attached to them via the `accessoryView`.  These buttons can be `selected/deselected` when the user clicks on them.  The `table` itself is made up from an `NSMutableArray` of objects that contain multiple `NSString` parameters, with the "name" parameter being on display in the table.

What I am trying to do now is when the button is selected, to add the corresponding `OBJECT` that links to the respective `"name"` parameter to an `NSMutableArray`.  The user is not selecting the cell, but rather, they are clicking on the button that is attached to the cell.

Here is my method that `selects/deselects` the `button` in each `cell`:

```
-(void)buttonTouched:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;

    if( [[btn imageForState:UIControlStateNormal] isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CheckBox1.png"]])
    {
        [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CheckBox2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        // statement to add object to NSMutableArray
    }
    else
    {
        [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CheckBox1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        // statement to remove object from NSMutableArray
    }

}


//Here is my code that shows how I initialize my button and cell in my UITableView

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        testButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [testButton setFrame:CGRectMake(280, 57, 25, 25)];
        [testButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CheckBox1.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [testButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CheckBox2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [testButton setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        [testButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTouched:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [testButton setTag:cell.tag];
        [cell setAccessoryView:testButton];
        //[cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];

    }

    // Configure the cell...
    TestObject *tObject = [[DataModel sharedInstance].testList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = tObject.testTitle;

    return cell;

}
```

My issue is not so much the actual adding of an object to the array, but deriving the respective cell from the button, and then deriving the correct object from that cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a way to link your cell to your button when you do it like this, you have a few options

1- Set tags on the button to be the corresponding index of the element in your array, that way you can get a hold of the cells through the tag property, this can have issues if you are deleting cells as you have to update your button tags.

2- Use a dictionary to map your buttons to your cells

So if you use the tag to mark the index you can use cellForRowAtIndexPath of UITableViewCell to get a hold of the cell , the data object should be in your datasourcce array with that index too..
Daniel

Comment: Thanks Daniel for your prompt reply.  I've updated my code to include the setting of the button's tag value to the corresponding cell's tag value.  Having done this, how would I retrieve the cell value, and by extension, the object from the button's tag value?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a view.tag to each button: e.g assign 101 to the first button, 102, to the second etc.

This tag then corresponds to a position in array, where you find your further info.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I've done in the past is set the tag of the button to the row of the cell. This only works if:

- you only have one section in your table
- you ALWAYS set the tag for the button in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` (because of dequeuing)
- your table is read only (meaning you don't allow cells to be deleted or moved)

For more complicated tables, you'll likely want a mapping from buttons to your objects.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of using an `NSMutableArray`, you could use an `NSMutableDictionary` and assign a key to the new item so it can be ordered more simply.